# Can I make a Java Number subclass automatically box and unbox?

Tags: java

I am creating some classes to represent Unsigned numbers for Java and deriving them from Number. One of my goals is to make them box and unbox primitive values but I can't get this to work nor find any discussion of how to achieve this elsewhere.

Can this be done and if so how?

Here is my not working code!

```
public class Unsigned8 extends Number implements Comparable<Unsigned8>{

public static final long MAX_VALUE = 256L;
public static final long MIN_VALUE = 0;
private long _Value;


public Unsigned8(long value)
{
    this._Value = value;
}

@Override
public byte byteValue() {
    return (byte) _Value;
}

@Override
public short shortValue() {
    return (short) _Value;
}

@Override
public int intValue() {
    return (int) _Value;
}

@Override
public long longValue() {
    return (long) _Value;
}

@Override
public double doubleValue() {
    return _Value;
}

@Override
public float floatValue() {
    return _Value;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Unsigned8 target) {
    return (int) (_Value - target._Value);
}
```

}

Comment: where s the code? sure you should be able to do it.

Comment: You need to change your compareTo so it return -1, 0 or +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. What I do is use an [Unsigned](http://code.google.com/p/java-unsigned/source/browse/trunk/unsigned/src/main/java/com/google/code/unsigned/Unsigned.java) helper class for `short` `int` and `long` so that your don't incur the overhead of a wrapper to support `unsigned` types. See the link for examples.

Comment: +1 especially for putting your Unsigned class under "BEER-WARE LICENSE". Didn't know about this license before. :)

Comment: FYI, Guava provides [similar](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedInts.html) utilities under `com.google.common.primitives`, in addition to basic wrapper class implementations.  There's no way to get those to autobox, though.

Answer (score 3):

No. You get a relation between primitives and its wrapper that follows:

```
Primitive type  Wrapper class
boolean         Boolean
byte            Byte
char            Character
float           Float
int             Integer
long            Long
short           Short
```

They are limited to these types. Documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

Comment: When it comes to `Boxing Conversion` then there is another one from `null` to the `null type`. (JLS 5.1.7) But not the other way around for `Unboxing Conversion`. But this is nitpicking, so +1 :)